# Access update SQL

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to update my Table (Referral) Field name (referdate) type Date
to be updated by using inputbox, where the user pass the number through the input box and then to this number to referdate to give me date + 2 days result. (example: inputbox 2 days, add 2 days to 20-12-2020 result is 22-12-2020)
the error I get (syntax error in the update statement)
my access version is 2013

my code below:

```
Dim S As Integer
    
S = InputBox(" How many days to follow", "Number of Days !")

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral" & _
"SET referdate = referdate" & Me.referdate + S & _
"where SRSno = " & Me.SRSno

Me.Refresh
```

Comment: Dim S As Integer
    
    S = InputBox(" How many days to follow", "Number of Days !")
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral SET [referdate]= " & DateAdd("d", S, [referdate]) & _
    " where [SRSno] = " & Me.SRSno & ""
    
    Me.Requery

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql), it seems that your statement might be including the existing column value being concatenated with the local variable.. Try this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral" & _
"SET referdate = " & Me.referdate + S & _
"where SRSno = " & Me.SRSno
```

The difference is subtle, but the Microsoft example shows adding a value as part of the query expression to the existing column value:

`SET OrderAmount = OrderAmount * 1.1,`

The alternative syntax for your case might be:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral" & _
"SET referdate = referdate + " & S & _
"where SRSno = " & Me.SRSno
```

In either case, notice that *referdate* only appears once in the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, unfortunately, i didn't work still I am receiving syntax error. however, I have changed my SQL statement to : DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral SET [referdate]= " & DateAdd("d", S, [referdate]) & _
    " where [SRSno] = " & Me.SRSno & "" it works but the result I receive is time value that I cant relate to instead of date value

Answer (score 0):

Include *DateAdd* and don't forget the spaces:

```vb
If Val(S) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Referral " & _
    "SET referdate = DateAdd('d', " & Val(S) & ", referdata) " & _
    "WHERE SRSno = " & Me.SRSno & ""
End If
```